# How to send HTTP request from android app to Heroku

Tags: java, android, http, heroku, twilio

I have a android app that uses the twilio sdk and is hosted by heroku server. I'm trying to push a button in my app to send a HTTP request to heroku to send a REST API request to Twilio to update my twiml URL. The current way i'm trying to send the the HTTP request is not working. I have looked through all of the examples that i could find and none of them show how to do this function. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

This is my code for trying to send the HTTP request to heroku

```
    holdButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://yourappnamehere.herokuapp.com/hello");

            try {
                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

                BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

                InputStream is = buf.getContent();

                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line);
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //setting a toast to see if this is being initiated
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "why wont it work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        ;

    });
```

This is my updated code including the volley library

```
            holdButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //setting up a request queue from Volley API
                    //RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    // Instantiate the cache
                    Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap

    // Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
                    Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

    // Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
                    mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);

    // Start the queue
                    mRequestQueue.start();

                    String url = "http://yourappnamehere.herokuapp.com/hello";

    // Formulate the request and handle the response.
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    // Do something with the response
                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    // Handle error
                                }
                            });

                    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
                    mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "why wont it work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   ;

   });
```

Comment: First of all use `AsyncTask` to make all network calls , because if you don't , it is going to give you an exception , `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Secondly, use `HttpURLConnection` class to make GET/POST calls on any url/server. It is much easier and simpler and `DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated.
[Here is a basic example in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a library like Google Volley which is pretty slick
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

HttpRequest is deprecated from API level 22. It would be best practice to avoid using that. Use  java.net.HttpUrlConnection instead.

However, if you still want to use it, the above code needs to be run on a thread other than the UI thread as mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: I have installed the Volley library for android and when i push the button nothing happens still. I'm new when it comes to HTTP request and RESTful API. How can i update my parameters to let twilio know that i want to use that URL immediately? Is this formatted correctly? All i'm trying to do is send a URL to Twilio to update my twiml. I have updated my code.

Comment: Have you added this to your Manifest file?                                          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />